# itunes could not connect to the ipad

Tags: ipad, locking, itunes

my friend used my ipad device now he gave the locked ipad with saying error

itunes could not connect to the ipad "TEMP" because it is locked with a passcode.you must enter your passcode on the ipad before it can be used with itunes. (From itunes)

iPad is disabled Connect to itunes (from ipad device).

Try to get some solutions for this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the iPad is passcode protected and the wrong passcode has been entered too many times, so the iPad is now disabled. You can unlock the iPad by connecting it to iTunes on the computer you last synced with.

Otherwise, you can restore your iPad in **recovery mode**. **This will delete all the data on the iPad.** Follow these steps: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4097

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For all

i have reboot the device using the Recboot and i have restored os.it was working perfect

thanks